# what is :<variablename> in CAST statement in PL SQL

Tags: plsql

I found a query like `select cast (:v as customtabletype) from dual`.

Not able to understand what is the meaning of above line, written as dynamic query.

Comment: 'CAST' function used for converting something as defined in 'customtabletype'. No idea what this 'customtabletype' is though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:<variablename>, in your case ":v", is what is known as a bind variable.

Essentially, this is a placeholder which is replaced with another value as the SQL statement is executed.

For more in-depth reading it is probably worth looking for bind variables in the Oracle documentation, as there is a lot of information available on why they're used and their benefits.